# INSERT INTO members cannot be executed

Tags: php, user-registration

This is the problematic part of code:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members 
(user, pass, mail, country, city, www, credo)
VALUES  ('$_POST[user]','$_POST[pass]', '$_POST[mail]',
'$_POST[country]', '$_POST[city]', '$_POST[www]', '$_POST[credo]')")
or die ("Error - Couldn't register user.");
```

I got the die error.
How could I find more specific part which cannot be executed ?
I tried to eliminate fields one by one - without result.

Comment: `or die ("Error - Couldn't register user. " . mysql_error());`

Comment: do -> or die(mysql_error()) and post the error

Comment: Try outputting your SQL query, and running it directly in the database. That will show you what isn't working. You should also look at moving away from `mysql_*` functions, as they're being deprecated.

Comment: Also, this code is probably vulnerable to SQL injection. Interpolating variables from `$_POST` directly into a query is dangerous.

Comment: Also, you need `'{$_POST['something']}'` instead of `'$_POST[something]'`.

Comment: Injecting arbitrary data into your SQL is **not** cool. [Escape your SQL properly](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) You shouldn't be doing anything this reckless under any circumstances.

Comment: Ok, I'll try all this things. Thanks a lot

Comment: @andrewsi, could you provide source of `mysql_*` functions being deprecated? Thanks.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour - it's on the manual page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated mysql functions are no longer being maintained, and may be removed from future versions of PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should present you the reason behind your failed query, and at the very least prevent some security concerns:

**Small Improvement**

```
// Run by each $_POST entry and set it to empty if not found
// Clean the value against tags and blank spaces at the edges
$dataArr = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $dataArr[$key] = ($value == "undefined") ? '' : strip_tags(trim($value));
}

// try to perform the INSERT query or die with the returned mysql error
$query = mysql_query("
  INSERT INTO members 
  (user, pass, mail, country, city, www, credo)
  VALUES (
    '".$dataArr["user"]."',
    '".$dataArr["pass"]."',
    '".$dataArr["mail"]."',
    '".$dataArr["country"]."',
    '".$dataArr["city"]."',
    '".$dataArr["www"]."',
    '".$dataArr["credo"]."'
  )
") or die ("Error:<br/>".mysql_error());
```

---

**Medium Improvement**

```
// Run by each $_POST entry and set it to empty if not found
// Clean the value against tags and blank spaces at the edges
$dataArr = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $dataArr[$key] = ($value == "undefined") ? '' : strip_tags(trim($value));
}

// escape everything
$query = sprintf("
    INSERT INTO members 
    (user, pass, mail, country, city, www, credo) 
    value ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
    mysql_real_escape_string($dataArr["user"]), 
    mysql_real_escape_string($dataArr["pass"]), 
    mysql_real_escape_string($dataArr["mail"]), 
    mysql_real_escape_string($dataArr["country"]), 
    mysql_real_escape_string($dataArr["city"]), 
    mysql_real_escape_string($dataArr["www"]), 
    mysql_real_escape_string($dataArr["credo"])
);

// try to perform the INSERT query or die with the returned mysql error
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error:<br/>".mysql_error());
```

---

**Advanced Improvement**

If you're starting a new project, or at a point where you can still change your ways, I vividly recommend the use of [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to prevent many security issues related the current database connection you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO members 
(user, pass, mail, country, city, www, credo)
VALUES  
('".$_POST['user']."','".$_POST['pass']."', '".$_POST['mail']."',
'".$_POST['country']."', '".$_POST['city']."', '".$_POST['www']."', '".$_POST['credo']."')")
```

Just a short warning. Inserting POST values directly into the database can cause security breaches. Be sure to validate and filter all user input before inserting them in the database.

Comment: This will work on older versions of PHP, when {$_POST['something']} will work on newer.

Answer (score 0):

Your Sql query is wrong.
Here

```
VALUES  ('$_POST[user]')
```

You have to use instead

```
 $_POST['user']
```

And you are inserting the values in the database directly..!!!
It's totally  a bad sense. Make it some escape

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['user']));
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['pass']));
$mail = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['mail']));
$country = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['country']));
$city = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['city']));
$www = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['www']));
$credo = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['credo']));
```

Then insert it in the database,

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members 
        (user, pass, mail, country, city, www, credo)
        VALUES  ($user,$pass, $mail,$country, $city, $www, $credo)")
        or die ("Error - Couldn't register user.");
```

The code is now secured and can insert in the database and is a clean code..